FastAPI - Axios GET call raises 422 unprocessable entity error
I have an API endpoint to retrieve values from a database:
class infintiescroll(BaseModel):
    offset: Optional[int] = 0 

@app.get("/api/allposts", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def allposts(nextpg : infintiescroll):
  try: 
   
   database = Databases(client).list_documents(database_id= 'xxx', collection_id= 'xxxx', 
   queries = [Query.select(['thread_content' , 'USER_ID', '$createdAt']), Query.order_desc('$createdAt'),Query.offset(nextpg.offset) ]) #.offset(params.offset)
   print(database)
   return database
  except Exception as e:   
     raise HTTPException(status_code= status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED , detail= e)  # Return an appropriate error status code

The front end call is
const fetchdata = async () => { 
     await axios.get('/api/allposts').then( (res) => setItems(res.data.documents))
     .catch((err) => console.log(err)); 
    }

This function only works when the api endpoint has no parameters ie  async def allposts(); when i have a parameter nextpg that i want to use to access the offest amount i get an error: "GET /api/allposts HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity. My other endpoints work well, i don't understand this situation. I want to be able to pass in an offset of x for the endpoint, with a default offset of 0. Any ideas as to why this isnt working??
A simple get request with an optional parameter.

The parameter itself isn't optional, read the docs: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters. Also it's not clear how you're actually planning to pass it as a query parameter, as your example request has no value.

In addition to the links provided above, please have a look at this answer, in order to better understand the 422 Unprocessable Entity error, as well as how to resolve it.

This answer and this answer might prove helpful as well. Also, see this answer, if you would like to know how to define query parameters using a Pydantic model in FastAPI.
